# How to debug missing drive slowing systemd boot process?

Tags: linux, systemd, hard-disk

After swapping an HDD for an SSD, I realized that my headless NAS system was booting slower... much *much* slower! I could not find anything in `systemd-analyze blame`, `systemd-analyze critical-chain`, or `systemctl list-units --failed`, so I just accepted it as the "new normal" and moved on.

A few days ago I had to do something in GRUB, and had to attach a monitor to the system. Upon booting I realized that there was a hanging line in systemd:

```
[ ***  ] Activating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/... (23s / 1min 30s)
```

Which made me wonder and inspect `lsblk` and `/etc/fstab`. And indeed! I remember not putting a swap partition on the SSD, but left the entry in `/etc/fstab`. So the system was waiting for a swap partition to come up, delaying the boot every time.

Now my question: How should I have debugged that, if not by looking at the physical boot screen? `systemd-analyze` doesn't seem to show these delaying/failing units at all.

Comment: I’d expect systemd-analyze to reveal the problem. You may be able to answer this yourself by comparing output with and without the problem fstab entry. It’s probably hiding behind a term that looks innocent

Comment: `systemctl list-units --failed`

Comment: @PonJar I tried that but didn't find anything. Especially since the delay should be 90s long, and the longest unit in both was around 10s.

Comment: @iBug it comes up empty...

Comment: I’d be interested to know if the output for critical-chain reports a similar time with and without the fstab entry. I think it’s normal for the kernel to mount devices which doesn’t use systemd. Alternatively you can configure systemd to mount devices, in which case I think you would see it’s impact. To diagnose the issue you could have tried `journalctl -p3` to list any errors, however the timeout handled the “error” so it might not show without a -p4 which would produce tons of output